# Upgrade MaaS from 1.5 to 1.6 on a running installation

Tags: upgrade, maas

Is it possible to upgrade an exsisting MaaS installation from 1.5 to 1.6 on 14.04?
Is there a PPA for this?

I'm currently running 1.5 on trusty. I've 16 nodes in the rack so far registered in MaaS, commissioned and ready. I've rolled out juju-core and have a juju bootstrap node. The main issue for the upgrade is, that the juju bootstrap node receives a new IP on every reboot. Renedering it practically useless. MaaS 1.4 on 12.04 does not have this problem, once the nodes are allocated, the ip sticks to the system. As one can [read here](http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs1.6/cluster-configuration.html#cluster-interface-management) in a newer version, there are more config options for static vs dynamic ip's in the cluster management.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you wait for maas 1.6 to be merged into the trusty default ppa.

Running the upgrade with ppa:maas-maintainers/stable, it appeared to work initially.

I have found a number of migration issues such as maas being unable to match nodes to pre-existing tags.